# How do I make this code stop after the first time it shows all the images?

Tags: android

Make it stop after the first time if finishes all images.

I have a postdelayed the just won't stop.

img is an ImageView

```
img.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        img.setImageResource(arrayOfIdentifiers[currentIndex++%imgs.length]);
        img.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Currently it shows all images on a loop.

Comment: I see no loop. Do you? Please remove the android-studio tag.

Comment: You are calling postDelayed() recursive. Indeed then it will never stop. No stackoverflow yet? Please explain why not.

Comment: i would expect a indexOutOfBound exception as well (unless memory consumption grows faster than array size)